# Algorithm for finding internally connected cluster of nodes within a graph from which no edge points outwards

Tags: c++, algorithm, search-engine, graph-algorithm, code-search-engine

I am representing my graph as a adjacency list. I want to know how can I find a cluster of nodes which are internally connected but no edge points outwards from them. Is there any well known algorithm out there which I can use?

for e.g.This is my graph.

```
1---->2
2---->1
2---->3
3---->1
3---->4
4---->5
5---->4
```

Here nodes 4 and 5 are internally connected. Yet no outside edge comes from this. This would be my answer. Similarly nodes 1,2,3 even though they form a cycle, do not fit the criteria as an outside edge emanates from node 3.
So it is not same as finding a cycle in a adjacency list.

Optional read: (why I need this)
I am working on a Ranking page (search engine) algorithm, nodes like 4 and 5 are called rank-sink.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component

Comment: @Anon: It is clear after reading your last line [optional read]. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could detect [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) using [Kosaraju](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm), [Tarjan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) or [Cheriyan-Mehldorn/Gabow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheriyan%E2%80%93Mehlhorn/Gabow_algorithm) algorithm.

After finding these components, you compress each strongly connected components into one single node (i.e. you represent a whole component by a single node).

In the resulting graph, you look for nodes with no outgoing edges. These nodes represent the components you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks. I did not get the compressing each strongly connected components into one single node. How do I do that?

Comment: @Anon: by substituting all references to any of the nodes in the component by the component itself, i.e. if `1, 2, 3` belongs to `A` component you substitute `5 ----> 1` with `5 ----> A` and remove entries like `1 ----> 2` entirely.